# Use <style> tag in TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, html, css, tinymce

I'm trying to add css in a `<style>` tag in a TinyMCE editor but when I validate the HTML changes, TinyMCE automatically put my css between comments.

Exemple :

If I type

```
<style>
h3{
   font-size:50px;
}
</style>
<h3>Hello</h3>
```

TinyMCE transforms that in :

```
<style>
h3{<!--
   font-size:50px;-->
}
</style>
<h3>Hello</h3>
```

In the setup I set :

```
extended_valid_elements: "pre[*],script[*],style[*]",
valid_children: \'+body[style|script],pre[script|div|p|br|span|img|style|h1|h2|h3|h4|h5],*[*]\',
valid_elements : \'*[*]\',
```

Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: I found a way to get around the problem but I hope if someone has a better solution : I insert an empty comment <!----> after <style> and before </style> and it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last poster on this thread (http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=25443) writes:

> TinyMCE produces XHTML and we wrap the style contents in a comment to
>   keep any XML parser from failing to parse the contents all browsers
>   support the comment syntax. --Spocke

so the answer is that **no, this cannot be changed**, because tiny mce not only is sworn to generate valid **`HTML`**, but must also generate valid (ughh) **`XHTML`**. Since they say `all browsers support the comment syntax` then it shouldn't really be a problem for you.

Answer (score 2):

If you put tinyMCE in fullpage mode, you can put styles in the `<head>`. It will not put the comment node there.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
tinyMCE.init({
        plugins : "fullpage",
});
</script>
```

Comment: this worked for me. Instead of just editing the html block, it will now edit a full HTML page, which is what I need for my email template system.